# How to change src attributes using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've got some pages which I need to change it's "source" tag "src" attributes, but I couldn't get anywhere by now.
The thing is, I could use getelemtbyId but these "source" tags has no ID.
Here is an example:

```
<section class="video-player">
<div id="91443f0a97f34c1294d05a8cad2d1bcc">
<video __idm_id__="297986">
<source src="https://example.org/1.mp4">
This browser cannot play .mp4, .ogg, or .webm files.Try using a different browser, such as Google Chrome.
</video>
</div>
<h3 class="hidden">No playable video sources found.</h3>
</section>
```

I searched and saw other topics, My question is different in 3 aspects:
1- source tags don't have IDs.
2- I need to change ALL source tag src attributes, how many they are, 1,3, or 10.
3- I can only use plain javascript.

Thanks!
Update 1:
Well, I tried to describe the problem in context so it may be useful to someone else, but I got really stuck here!
The problem is that I'm trying to create a tampermonkey script for chrome to convert `src="https://example.com/ex.mp4"` to `src="http://example.com/ex.mp4"` because my company shapes https traffic so heavily we can't watch video tutorials.
Using none of the answers below I couldn't achieve this. simply change https in src attributes to http.

Comment: can use `document.getElementsByTagName("source")` to retrieve them all.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('source')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
 var source = document.getElementsByTagName('source');
//the source element will be array of all source elements in the html
    var src = source[0].getAttribute("src"); //old Source of first source element
    var newsrc = source[0].setAttribute("src",'new source value'); //set new src of first source element
```

Comment: I used this method, along with `waitForKeyElements ( "source", changeSrc);` because content was being served using ajax, that was why I couldn't get it to work at first, Just needed to wait until it loaded completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.body.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) for this

```
var sourcesNodeList = document.body.querySelectorAll('source');

// cast it to an array so you can use iterative methods on it
Array.prototype.sourcesNodeList.forEach(function (source) {
    // do something with source.src
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the sources, then you can just use selector to `video source` to get all of them:

```js
// Use more detailed selector to get the one on your example.
var sources = document.querySelectorAll('video[__idm_id__="297986"] source');
var len = sources.length, i;
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    // Apply something to source.
    console.log(sources[i].src);
}
```

```html
<section class="video-player">
<div id="91443f0a97f34c1294d05a8cad2d1bcc">
<video __idm_id__="297986">
<source src="https://example.org/1.mp4">
This browser cannot play .mp4, .ogg, or .webm files.Try using a different browser, such as Google Chrome.
</video>
</div>
<h3 class="hidden">No playable video sources found.</h3>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try with that:

```
var source = document.getElementsByTagName("source")

for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    source[i].src = 'LINK HERE';
}
```